# Angular 4 Handling JWT Tokens

Tags: angular, jwt

I have the following Typescript method that can do a call to a service which is in turn going to return me a User object with a JWT token stuffed in it:

```
populate() {
    // If JWT detected, attempt to get & store user's info
    if (this.jwtService.getToken()) {
      this.apiService.get('/user')
      .subscribe(
        data => this.setAuth(data.user),
        err => this.purgeAuth()
      );
    } else {
      // Remove any potential remnants of previous auth states
      this.purgeAuth();
    }
  }
```

Here is how my user.model.ts is:

```
export class User {
  email: string;
  token: string;
  username: string;
  bio: string;
  image: string;
}
```

For a simple demo application, I would like to get rid of the call to a backend service and rather have a standard username and password and use this standard credentials for logging in!

I know that I could generate this JWT token, but not sure how. In effect, I would like to do the following:

Say I have a username and password captured as constants like:

```
const user = 'abcdef'
const pass = 'abcdef'
```

I would like to create a new User model like:

```
let userModel = new User(
  // set all the fields
  // How do I generate a static JWT token for the above user and password that is valid for 2 hours?
)
```

I will then bypass the call to the API and use the static JWT token for further calls to my Angular 4 application. Any ideas?

Comment: I have two doubts. 1: What's the point of generating `JWT` on `client side`? 2: Why do you have `user model` with `JWT` inside instead of having `token` with `sub` (user) inside?

Comment: I agree there is no point generating the token on the client, but I do not want to implement anything on the backend as this will just be some demo application!

Comment: I would later on start to integrate more users and only at that point in time, I would need the token to come from the backend server!

Comment: Yes, I got this, but can't you skip this process? Like REM the `AuthGuard` if you have any? Anyway, this article should come in handy: https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2014/11/27/creating-json-web-token-in-javascript.html

Comment: I do not want to skip the process as like I said, I will later add the server side JWT!

Comment: Could you point me how I could do it? I came across this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-simple

Comment: All I need to do is to create a new instance of a User and generate the JWT token from it using the jwt-simple library

Comment: How do I instantiate a new type?

Comment: Lib looks simple and okay. Where's the problem now? What do you mean by instantiating a new type? Do you mean: `let user: User = new User()`?

Comment: You can also create some `export class JWTUtil` and `static string generateJWT()` method inside and use it in the constructor of `User` model.

Comment: Could you post an answer!